# Dynamic Dropdown with different Sql Table as the View MVC C#

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a SQL Server table as a source with the CRUD commands.
The table2_ID column comes from table2 (foreign key).
Now when editing and creating Table1 entries I want a dropdown for `table_ID` column in Table1  with option: `Name` of Table2 and the `ID` must then be saved as the value.

**What does the code in the controller look like to get the data from Table2 (name and ID)?
and what does the code look like in the view to show the data as a dropdown with name as an option and id as a value?**

Table1:

| number | table2_ID | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2 | 12.12.2021 |
| 32 | 3 | 13.12.2021 |

Table2

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | axis |
| 3 | bot |

```
    / GET: Table1/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }        
 
            var table1 = await _context.Table1.FindAsync(id);
            if (table1 == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(table1);
        }

    [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("number, table2_ID, date")]       Table1 table1)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(table1);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(table1);
        }
    //Create view 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="number" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="number" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="number" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="table2_ID" class="control-label"></label> 
                <input asp-for="table2_ID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="table2_ID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="date" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="date" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="date" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please share your model design?

Comment: public class Table1{public int ID {get; set;} public datetime date {get; set;} public string Table2_ID{get; set;}} and public class Table2{public int ID {get; set;} public string name {get; set;}}

Comment: Hi, I have shared an answer below, pls check. If any problems, pls follow up to let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does the code in the controller look like to get the data from
> Table2 (name and ID)?

You can get the Table2 data like below:

```
var data = _context.Table2.ToList();
```

> and what does the code look like in the view to show the data as a
> dropdown with name as an option and id as a value

You need firstly store the dropdownlist value in `ViewBag`:

```
 ViewBag.table2= new SelectList(data,"ID","name");
```

And use the `ViewBag` like below:

```
<select asp-for="Table2_ID" asp-items="@ViewBag.table2" class="form-control">
     <option selected disabled value="">--- Choose ---</option>
</select>
```

---

Whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class Table1 { 
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public DateTime date { get; set; } 
    public string Table2_ID { get; set; } 
}
public class Table2 { 
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string name { get; set; } 
}
```

View:

```
@model Table1

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="date" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="date" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="date" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Table2_ID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Table2_ID" asp-items="@ViewBag.table2"   class="form-control">
                        <option selected disabled value="">--- Choose ---</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Table2_ID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
// GET: Table1/Create
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.table2 = new SelectList(_context.Table2.ToList(), "ID", "name");

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,date,Table2_ID")] Table1 table1)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(table1);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    ViewBag.table2 = new SelectList(_context.Table2.ToList(), "ID", "name",table1.Table2_ID);
    return View(table1);
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }     
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you very very much, it works